# Revamp "XX Users earned this badge" page

Tags: feature-request, badges, review

If you click on a badge under the [Badges page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges), say [Announcer (on TeX.SE)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/57/announcer), you receive the following view:

[image]

For long question titles, it's not even possible to see who earned this badge for that specific question. I think the updated "Review history" page has a more suitable way of displaying this content. For example, consider the [First Posts review page (on TeX.SE)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/history):

[image]

Most likely only columns 1, 2 and 4 would be required here. Regardless, the presentation of the post titles wrap as needed, without cluttering the view with user badge lists (which doesn't add value on that page).

Comment: Part of the problem is that TeX.SE uses such a huge font for the question links in that list.  [It's nowhere near as bad on math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/badges/23/nice-answer), for example.  (Actually, I think it might be a bug in the TeX.SE style sheet.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen It happens also on Math.SE; it's impossible to see who earned the badge for [The Tuesday birthday problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87436/the-tuesday-birthday-problem-why-does-the-probability-change-when-the-father-s/87457#87457)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

As you can see, someone (or people) in SE decided to revamp the page for better readability:

[image]

We can all see the user who earned the badge, the post that got them the badge, and when they got the badge. Problem solved!