# Meta participation vs main reputation and associated badges

Tags: support, reputation, per-site-meta, daily-reputation-badges

[Meta.SO runs as a stand-alone site on the SE network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91333/168244). Therefore, it has its own reputation system and, consequently, votes and badges are easily identifiable. This is different on the *child*-Meta sites elsewhere. On these sites *reputation* is substituted for *participation* which is [measured differently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145151/168244). However, it is still possible to obtain reputation-related badges. Even the badge list on these sites reference a form of reputation required to obtain them, yet no such measure exists.

What merit is used to awarded Mortarboard, Epic and Legendary badges on per-meta sites when there is no visible user reputation associated with them?

---

As an example, consider [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com) and its [Meta](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com). Up to date, 7 people have received [Mortarboard](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/41/mortarboard) without a tangible measure of how.

[image]

A related question was posted a while back on TeX.SE's meta: [Badges on Meta vs Main](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3120/5764). There's also a related post on Meta.SO: [How to calculate per site meta reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172242/168244)

Comment: That's weird. Stefan Kottowitz has no bronze badges, but appears on this list.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi must be a display bug... you can't get to 86.6k rep without earning at least 1 bronze badge!

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi: It is related to an issue in the display of the information. See another question of mine that is somewhat related: [Revamp “XX Users earned this badge” page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160839/168244)

Comment: @HugoDozois You can certainly get to 86.6K rep without earning any bronze badge (check the screenshot a bit more carefully, we are talking _Meta_ badges).

Comment: @Yannis True about rep, but with 75 silver badges, provided that most of silver badge are actually an extension of a bronze badge... (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/users/213/stefan-kottwitz 158 bronze)

Comment: @HugoDozois Yes, there's most certainly a display bug there (or perhaps a rather aggressive cache). Although there are a couple of silver badges than don't have bronze equivalents, 75 is too many to have earned without a single bronze one.

Comment: Related: [Should I really have been awarded mortarboard on a Per-site meta?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78603/should-i-really-have-been-awarded-mortarboard-on-a-per-site-meta)